# How do I write this data into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I was doing a python exercise and I wanted put the author, tag, and text into a csv file, but I am having trouble figuring how to do so.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import csv
res = requests.get('https://quotes.toscrape.com')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup (res.text,'lxml')
#soup

author = soup.select('.col-md-8')
example = author[1]

example.select('.text')
for item1 in example.select(".text"):
    print(item1.text)

example.select('.tag')
for item2 in example.select(".tag"):
    print(item2.text)

example.select ('div span')
for item3 in example.select(".author"):
   print(item3.text)

file_to_output = open('QuotesToScrape.csv','w',newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow(['Text','Tag','Author'])
csv_writer.writerows([[item3.text,item2.text,item1.text],['4','5','6']])
file_to_output.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## Get the html from the page at your url
request = requests.get('https://quotes.toscrape.com')

## Create a BS object from the request text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, features="html.parser")

## Every block of text is a div with class="quote" so 
## lets start by pulling all of those
quotes = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "quote"})

## Before we iterate over all the quotes lets make a new csv
f = open("test.csv", "w")

## Lets write the headers into the csv
f.write("quote,author\n")

## Now lets iterate over all of those quotes
for each in quotes:

    ## Now that we have each broken out you can find the individual tags you need
    quote = each.find("span", {"class": "text"}).text

    ## Each author is in a small tag so this one is easy
    author = each.find("small").text

    ## Now lets write each quote/author to the csv
    f.write(f'{quote},{author}\n')

## Now we close the csv file
f.close()
```

I commented for clarity and understanding, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'text': ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'],
    'tag': [1, 2, 3],
    'author': ['author 1', 'author 2', 'author 3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Output:

```
| text   | tag | author   |
| ------ | --- | -------- |
| text 1 | 1   | author 1 |
| text 2 | 2   | author 2 |
| text 3 | 3   | author 3 |
```

Then you can use `to_csv()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv(
    'QuotesToScrape.csv',
    sep = ',',
    index = False
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `text` `tag` and `author` in a list. Then you need to write it into csv. You can use `zip` to group `(text1, tag1, author1), (text2, tag2, author2)...so on`

```py
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import csv
res = requests.get('https://quotes.toscrape.com')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup (res.text,'lxml')
#soup

author = soup.select('.col-md-8')
example = author[1]


# for item1 in example.select(".text"):
#     print(item1.text)

# for item2 in example.select(".tag"):
#     print(item2.text)

# for item3 in example.select(".author"):
#     print(item3.text)

text_tag_author = zip([i.text.replace(';', '') for i in example.select(".text")], 
                      [i.text.replace(';', '') for i in example.select(".tag")], 
                      [i.text.replace(';', '') for i in example.select(".author")])


file_to_output = open('QuotesToScrape.csv','w',newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output,delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow(['Text','Tag','Author'])
# for each_row in text_tag_author:
#     print(each_row)
csv_writer.writerows(text_tag_author)
# csv_writer.writerows([[item3.text,item2.text,item1.text],['4','5','6']])
file_to_output.close()
```

Comment: @mrsir217 hey great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem, so it won't pop up again.